# How to use a portion of the data?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, dataset, mnist

I want to use a portion randomly from the MNIST dataset. Can you help me please? Now the output shape (i.e. `Out`) is 60000 but I want to get about 2000:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784) / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784) / 255

x_train.shape  # Out: (60000, 748)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just take a slice of `x_train`:

```
new_x_train = x_train[:2000]
```

If the data in `x_train` is ordered (i.e. digits of class 1, then class 2, etc.), then you should first shuffle the data and then slice it:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.arange(x_train.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
x_train = x_train[indices]
```

Read more about slicing in [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.2/reference/arrays.indexing.html).